# What is the reason of this error in ansible 2.7.10 - "ERROR! playbook entries must be either a valid play or an include statement|"

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I am watching a tutorial of Ansible where I have to deploy a playbook. The play-book code are following:

```
- name:"Do a demo"
  hosts:groupA

  tasks:!!seq
    - name:demo task 1
      debug:!!seq
        msg:"this is task 1"

    - name:demo task 2
      debug:!!seq
        msg:"this is task 2"

- name:"Do another demo"
  hosts:groupB

  tasks:!!seq
    - name:demo task 3
      debug:!!seq
      msg:"this is task 3"

    - name:demo task 4
      debug:!!seq
        msg:"this is task 4"
```

When I tried to deploy the above play-book using `ansible-playbook -i hosts demoplays.yaml` command, the error was raised:-

```
ERROR! playbook entries must be either a valid play or an include statement

The error appears to have been in '/home/user/demoplays.yaml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name:"Do a demo"
  ^ here
```

At first I considered as yaml syntax error,however YAML linter   validated it was correct. I using  ansible 2.7.10 on my elementary OS Loki system. I am just started to learning Ansible and YAML and have not found any hint why that error happening!

Comment: Although that is valid YAML, it looks very much that you forgot to put a space after the value indicator (`:`) on almost every line. As it is this is a list of two, multi-line, plain scalars, and not a list of mappings

Comment: Next time please include the link to your tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your YAML is equivalent to:

```
[
  "name:\"Do a demo\" hosts:groupA\ntasks:!!seq - name:demo task 1 debug:!!seq msg:\"this is task 1\"\n- name:demo task 2 debug:!!seq msg:\"this is task 2\"", 
  "name:\"Do another demo\" hosts:groupB\ntasks:!!seq - name:demo task 3 debug:!!seq msg:\"this is task 3\"\n- name:demo task 4 debug:!!seq msg:\"this is task 4\""
]
```

Which is probably not what you want. Try to change this so that the items of the root level sequence in your YAML become mappings:

```
- name: "Do a demo"
  hosts: groupA

  tasks: !!seq
    - name: demo task 1
      debug: !!seq
        msg: "this is task 1"

    - name: demo task 2
      debug: !!seq
        msg: "this is task 2"

- name: "Do another demo"
  hosts: groupB

  tasks: !!seq
    - name: demo task 3
      debug: !!seq
        msg: "this is task 3"

    - name: demo task 4
      debug: !!seq
        msg: "this is task 4"
```

Please note that I not only added a space after the colon making it into a value indicator, I also indented the `msg: "this is task 3"` to confirm to the other `msg` keys.

Comment: Yes, just added two spaces after `:` as you said and it worked nicely!  However, would you please little more elaborate why  it need those spaces to execute properly?

Comment: In YAML each key value pair of a mapping is separated by a value indicator. Unless both key and value are quoted, that value indicator consists of a colon followed by a space. Without that space you just have a non-quoted scalar with a colon somewhere in the middle, and not a key-value pair. Such a non-quoted scalar can span multiple lines (newlines converted to spaces)